# Кликабельная картинка в приложении android

Tags: java, android, изображения

Всем привет.
Есть 4 картинки с разными схемами автомобиля как во вложении. как можно обработать клик на колесо? и поменять цвет колеса?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно нарезать картинку и колеса сделать отдельными картинками, а потом подменять их

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 колеса должны быть например четырьмя кнопками. Для начала вы берете картинку с колесом, делаете дубликат, одно оставляете в том виде, в каком оно есть, а другое делаете, например с красным оттенком. Затем помещаете эти две картинки в папку `Drawable` и там же создаете файл, например: `wheel_color_condition_state` и в селекторе делаете так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel_color_red" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel_color_standard" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

`Ну и в макете 4х кнопок в фоном задаете этот файл:

```
android:background="@drawable/wheel_color_condition_state"
```

Таким образом, когда вы будете нажимать на колесо, оно будет применять картинку с красным колесом, а когда не будете нажимать, картинку стандартной расцветки.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1:**

Положить сверху кнопку, которая выглядит точно так же. При нажатии менять картинку методом `setBackground(Drawable bg)`

wheel_1.setBackground(R.drawable.colored_wheel_1)

**Вариант 2:**

Сразу сверху положить кнопку второго цвета и сделать ее прозрачной:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/wheel_1"
android:background="@drawable/wheel_1" 
android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

или

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/wheel_1"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">
```

При нажатии ставить прозрачность на visible:

```
wheel_1.setVisibility(VISIBLE)
```

Разумеется, для разных колес нужные отдельные картинки (задние одинаковые, можно обойтись и общими).